# Why console.log doesn't work as an argument?

Tags: javascript

In javascript there is a callback, and functions are first-class objects right? so i can pass a function as an argument however if i pass console.log() it doesn't work why is that isn't it  a function as well?

```
setTimeout(function(){console.log("hello")},5000);
```

this code is valid however

```
setTimeout(console.log("hello"),5000);
```

produces an error, why is that?

Comment: Because you are queuing up the *result* of `console.log(...)` (it returns `undefined`), not the actual call to `console.log(...)`.

Comment: you should be able to pass it around willy-nilly since they recently bound  `this` to `console` for its methods...

Answer (score 3):

When you call `console.log` with some argument, the argument is printed to console and the function returns `undefined`.

So when you do:

```
setTimeout(console.log("hello"),5000);
```

`"hello"` will be printed, but what you're essentially doing is:

```
setTimeout(undefined, 5000);
```

In the other example (that works) you create a new function, but you do not *call* it. So you pass this new function to `setTimeout`, and that is why it works.

Comment: Aha! Thank you that was really helpful :)

Answer (score 3):

The reason that the following code

```
setTimeout(console.log("hello"),5000);
```

fails is because `console.log()` is invoked directly inside the setTimeout parameter and it always returns undefined (more info: [MDN Documentation on Console.log](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log)). This means you are essentially running `setTimeout(undefined,5000);`

You need to provide a function declaration that is not invoked. If you wrap the code inside of a function declaration and do not invoke it, setTimeout will invoke it for you after the specified time lapses. This is why your first statement works, you provide a function declaration:

```
setTimeout(function(){console.log("hello")},5000);
```

If you **had** invoked the function you provided in the first parameter it would also return undefined and "hello" would be output immediately.

So if you provide a function declaration it will work:

```
setTimeout(()=>{console.log("hello")},5000);
```

Another way to use console.log directly without a function declaration is to bind it to a variable (more info: [MDN Documentation on Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)). An example using `.bind` prototype:

```
setTimeout(console.log.bind(null,"hello"),5000);
```

The code above binds "hello" to invocation of console.log. The first parameter is `null` in this example but it is the `this` context.

setTimeout also allows you to pass variables that you want the function to be invoked with. [See MDN Documentation on setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Talk:DOM/Window.setTimeout)

For example to pass a variable:

```
setTimeout(console.log,5000,'hello');
```

In the above example you are telling setTimeout to invoke console.log in 5 seconds with the variable (in this case a sting) of 'hello'.

Answer (score 1):

Invoking `console.log('hello')` will return `undefined` so you are not really passing it to `setTimeout`, It will print "hello" though but not inside a callback.
In most cases it wont throw an error (as you can see in the example below).

What you can do however is pass `console.log` (the function) and a [3rd argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) the string "hello" in our case.

Running example with all 3 cases:

```js
setTimeout(console.log("hello"),500);
setTimeout(function(){console.log("hello2")},500);
setTimeout(console.log,500,"hello3");
```

Answer (score 0):

It produces an error since it evaluates `console.log(...)`, which evaluates to `undefined`, and thus is not a function.

Comment: Answer would be improved by showing correct usage, e.g. `setTimeout(console.log, 5000, "hello");`

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout accepts the function as a parameter, not the function call. console.log() is basically invoking the function/method but setTimeout requires the reference or more specifically called the callback.

In your example:-

```
setTimeout(function(){console.log("hello")},5000);
```

you can call it like

```
var callback = function(){console.log("hello")};
setTimeout(callback,5000);
```

The callback will be called by setTimeout later in future. I hope it clears everything.